# How to define flatMap for a class with covariant/contravariant type parameters?

Tags: scala, monads, covariance, contravariance, for-comprehension

Let's say we have a class that has a covariant and a contravariant type parameter:

```
sealed trait Pipe[-I,+O,+R]
// case subclasses
```

And we have monadic operations defined for instances of this class:

```
object Pipe {
    def flatMap[I,O,Ri,R](p: Pipe[I,O,Ri], f: Ri => Pipe[I,O,R]): Pipe[I,O,R] =
        ...
}
```

To be able to use `for`-comprehension, we need that `flatMap` is a method of the trait itself:

```
sealed trait Pipe[-I,+O,+R] {
    def flatMap[I,O,Ri,R](f: Ri => Pipe[I,O,R]): Pipe[I,O,R] =
        Pipe.flatMap(this, f);
}
```

However, this does not compile, it fails with

> contravariant type `I` occurs in covariant position in type `(R) => Pipe[I,O,R1]` of value `f`.

(A similar error occurs for covariant type parameters as well.)

I understand the restriction and why the problem occurs. But is there some workaround, how to define `flatMap` on the trait using `Pipes.flatMap` with the same semantics as above? Perhaps using some implicit conversions and/or an intermediate builder class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simply,

```
implicit def pipeFlatMap[I, O, A](pipe: Pipe[I, O, A]) = new {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Pipe[I, O, B]) = Pipe.flatMap(pipe, f)
}
```

If your `Pipe` permits implementing `point`, i.e. `def point[I, O, A](a: A): Pipe[I, O, A]`, then implementing a full `scalaz.Monad` typeclass could be useful, as Scalaz's implicits would give you `flatMap` and many other monadic operations for free:

```
implicit def pipeMonad[I, O] = new Monad[({type λ[α]=Pipe[I, O, α]})#λ] {
  // TODO implement point and bind
}
```